# Issues with a normal map baking

Tags: baking, normal-map, artifacts

I don't understand what's going wrong when baking my normal map. You can see the strange result on a pic.
It's a non-manifold geometry mesh and the text on a tire has a bad topology. Can it affect on a normal map baking?
I saw about 5 guides on youtube, made the same things, tried max ray distance from 0.00005 to 1m, with cage and without, but have the same result or just empty normal map.
Any tips will be very helpful.[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, have you checked the normals? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I have checked the normals, it looks ok. Shared the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems:

- Your unwrapping is bad, the UVs of the low-poly are overlapping, so when it bakes it bakes the letters then erases them, you need to unwrap again, as you've marked seams it will unwrap correctly.
- The image is pretty small for the thing you want to bake (the letters), you need to either scale it up, or scale up the faces of the UV that are supposed to bake the letters (and scale down the rest as the other faces of the UV are completely useless, your tire is flat)
- Give the bake a bit of *Extrusion* (like 0.02) otherwise it won't be able to scan the letters. Put the *Maximum Distance* at 0 (illimited), you don't need to limit the distance.
- Plug your *Image Texture* into a *Normal Map* that you plug into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*. Switch to *Material* or *Rendered* preview to see something, in *Solid* mode you won't see any normal map effect.